# Volume change listener?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, media, volume

Is there any way to listen for volume changes with an Android service and react to that?

Btw: How does the Google music app allow the user to control the media volume even when the music is playing in the background?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out `registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(ComponentName broadcastReceiver);`

Define a `BroadcastReceiver` that handles `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON`. The recieved `intent` includes a single extra field, `EXTRA_KEY_EVENT`, containing the key event that caused the broadcast. You can use this key event to get which key was pressed.

EDIT:
This is just a sample code. syntax errors may be there.

```
// in onCreate of activity
registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mediaReceiver ); 

// later somewhere in activity.
MediaButton_Receiver mediaReceiver = new MediaButton_Receiver();

class MediaButton_Receiver implements BroadcastReceiver {
     void onReceive(Intent intent) {

          KeyEvent ke = (KeyEvent)intent.getExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT); 
          if (ke .getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {

          }
          // Similarly other key codes .......
     } 
}
```

Unregister the receiver in `onPause()` or `onStop()`

Comment: Can you give an example of that please?

Comment: I have added the sample code. But there are syntax errors in it. Also should check action key down or key up. For start this is good, add it later.

Comment: Also do not forget to unregister the receiver otherwise other applications using the media button event may get affected.

Comment: @userSeven7s I don't get any intents when changing the volume using the volume rocker but I do get for the button on my headset. Should it work for the volume rocker as well?

Comment: // should be put in onResume I think
registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mediaReceiver );