# How to launch android application when volume key is pressed android

Tags: android, launch

i want to launch my application when the volume turned to very low..

Edit:

Or my application should run in background and it should listen to the volume changes.. I think it sounds good...

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? if yes then u must post that code here

Comment: not really(sorry for that)..to start my app first i need to check some basic possibilities... very soon i will come up with the code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use registerMediaButtonEventReceiver with a BroadcastReceiver that handles ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.

This thread explains it:
[Volume change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130455/volume-change-listener)