# How to catch that volume was changed?

Tags: android

I use `SeekBar` for setting volume. I do the following:

1. I get current volume by `getStreamVolume()` and pass it to `SeekBar` element by `setProgress()`.
2. I listen messages from the `SeekBar` element by `onStopTrackingTouch()` and set volume by `setStreamVolume()`.
   It works.

But user can change volume by hardware volume controls. I'd like to catch it and change `SeekBar` pointer position appropriately. How can I do it?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/7130455/1300995

Comment: I seen it, but it doesn't work for me on my HTC. I tried to do as described in http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/allowing-applications-to-play-nicer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
    //set your SeekBar  
    return true;
  }

 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

The question/answer that biegleux pointed you to is only for the "media keys" on an attached headset, not for the hardware volume up/down keys on the phone itself.